# Using id="#{...}" causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty id attribute is not allowed

Tags: jsf, el

I need to solve my problem with generating dynamic ID for some components in JSF.

Have a look at this example:

```
<h:outputText id="#{bean.id}" value="#{bean.value}" />
```

My problem is that I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty id attribute is not allowed
```

The ID of the component is empty when I look at generated HTML output. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Its unique id from database.

Comment: You are right. I am using it inside datatable. Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> *You are right. I am using it inside datatable.*

Then this can happen if the `#{bean}` represents the currently iterated object as declared in `var` attribute like so:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{someBean.beans}" var="bean">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText id="#{bean.id}" value="#{bean.value}" />
```

The `id` (and `binding`) attribute of a JSF component is evaluated during view build time, that moment when the JSF component tree needs to be composed. However, the `#{bean}` is only available during view render time, that moment when `<h:dataTable>` needs to iterate over all objects and generate HTML table rows for each of them. The `#{bean}` is thus not available during view build time and evaluates to `null` which ultimately gets EL-coerced to an empty string. And hence the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty id attribute is not allowed`.

You've basically 3 options:

1. Use a view build time tag instead to iterate over a collection. You'd only need to write all HTML boilerplate yourself:

   ```
   <table>
       <c:forEach items="#{someBean.beans}" var="bean">
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <h:outputText id="#{bean.id}" value="#{bean.value}" />
   ```
2. Use a plain HTML element:

   ```
   <h:dataTable value="#{someBean.beans}" var="bean">
       <h:column>
           <span id="#{bean.id}">#{bean.value}</span>
   ```
3. Don't set a dynamic ID, but a fixed ID. JSF will ensure of uniqueness in HTML output by prepending it with row index of the table:

   ```
   <h:dataTable value="#{someBean.beans}" var="bean">
       <h:column>
           <h:outputText id="id" value="#{bean.value}" />
   ```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) (you can substitute "JSTL" with "dynamic ID")

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea was that I wanted for each column connect tooltip from primefaces which requires the ID to be connected at.

Comment: BalusC: You never had the need for a dynamic ID? Without dynamic ID's how would you use a Reusable facelet tag/component, more than once on a JSF page?

Comment: @bch: Give it a fixed ID. E.g. `<my:tag id="foo">` with `<h:some id="#{id}">`. Or make it a composite component.

Comment: you saved my life with the <span> suggestion! Thank you :)