# <c:forEach> not recognized anymore after migration JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, foreach, jstl, jsf-2.2

I am upgrading my application from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.

I am trying a below simple forEach tag but it not showing anything inside the loop.

```
<table 
    id="tab${sectionId}"
    border="0" 
    cellpadding="0" 
    cellspacing="0" 
    width="100%"
    class="listingTable"
>
    <c:forEach
        var="row" 
        rowStatus="index"
        items="#{bean.department.userActivities}"
    >
        <tr>
            <td>
                test
            </td>
         </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The value test is not showing up. Has the c:forEach implementaion changed?

I tried replacing  with  but  has some other issue. It is rendering the content inside it. But if I have a component inside , I am not able to assign a backing bean value as ID of the component. Example is as below

```
<table 
    id="tab${sectionId}"
    border="0" 
    class="listingTable"
>
    <t:dataList
        var="row" 
        rowIndexVar="index"
        value="#{bean.department.userActivities}"
    >
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText id="#{row.activityCode}">test1</h:outputText>
        </h:column>
    </t:dataList>
</table>
```

So, with . I am not able to assign backing bean property as ID of the component. I am receiving the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: component identifier must not be a zero-length String "

Can anyone please help me in understanding as to why the c:forEach tag is not working. I have huge code which is using forEach tag. With upgrade, I will have to remove every forEach if it is no more supported in JSF2 :(

Answer (score 2):

JSTL taglib/XML namespace URI has changed forth and back across JSTL/JSF/Facelets versions.

For JSF on JSP with JSTL 1.0, it is

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
```

For JSF on [JSP with JSTL 1.1+](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html), it is

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

For [JSF 1.x on Facelets](https://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#taglib-available-jstl) with JSTL 1.1+, it is

```
<xxx xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
```

For [JSF 2.x on Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/c/tld-summary.html) with JSTL 1.2+, it is

```
<xxx xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
```

For [JSF 2.2+ on Facelets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/c/tld-summary.html) with JSTL 1.2+, it is

```
<xxx xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
```

Make sure you pick the right one.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, as to the underlying functional requirement which you're actually ultimately trying to solve, head to the following related questions for a thought:

- [Using id="#{...}" causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty id attribute is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884801/using-id-causes-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-empty-id-attribute/)
- [How to use EL with <ui:repeat var> in id attribute of a JSF component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358604/how-to-use-el-with-uirepeat-var-in-id-attribute-of-a-jsf-component)

Comment: Thanks BalusC! I was initially using wrong namespace. I am using 2.2 version and hence changed the namespace as per you reply. However, I ran into another issue- The values of the components inside c:forEach are not bound to backingbean anymore. Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: You're welcome. Just press Ask Question button if you have a new question.