# JSTL c:forEach tag not working for El expression in JSF

Tags: jsf, foreach, jstl, el

In trying to solve a larger problem using JSF, I noticed that I can't seem use c:forEach to iterate over lists.  Research has taught me that there are several different versions now, and I believe I'm using JSF 2.2.

I've tried some different settings on the web.xml and in the xmlns:c tag with no result.

The following is a test file to demonstrate what is not working:
index.html includes Content/Content_index.xhtml which includes Content/Recursive_Box.xhtml:

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="#{LoginBean.currentUser.loggedOn}">
            <ui:include src="#{MainBean.setLayout(0,0,0)}"></ui:include>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <ui:include src="#{MainBean.setLayout(0,6,0)}"></ui:include>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</html>
```

Content_index.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="#{LoginBean.currentUser.loggedOn}">
            <title>
                Bubble Up!
            </title>
<!--<c:set value="#{TargetBean.PullStructure(LoginBean.currentUser.userIndex)}" var="tickle"></c:set>-->
            <ui:include src="Recursive_Box.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="box" value="#{TargetBean.structure}" />
            </ui:include>
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</html>
```

Recursive_Box.xhtml
(Only the first 2 tests work: Static and Test1)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    #{box}<br/>

    #{box.boxList}<br/>
    #{box.getBoxList()}<br/>
    #{box.boxList.get(0)}<br/>

    #{box.boxList.size()}<br/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "1" end = "5">
        Static<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "0" end = "#{box.boxList.size()}">
        Test1<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "1" end = "#{box.boxList.size()}">
        Test2<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var = "i" items = "#{box.getBoxList()}">
        Test2<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "1" end = "#{box.getBoxList().size()}">
        Test3<br/>
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "1" end = "${box.boxList.size()}">
        Test4<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var = "i" items = "${box.getBoxList()}">
        Test5<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "1" end = "${box.getBoxList().size()}">
        Test6<br/>
    </c:forEach>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I should be able to iterate over a given list, but the for my tests, I'm getting the following output:

```
Main.Box@50eb0e0
[Main.Box@2452c4d, Main.Box@5fd03294, Main.Box@4c97b69b, Main.Box@3c6e8659, Main.Box@17e2e2dd]
[Main.Box@2452c4d, Main.Box@5fd03294, Main.Box@4c97b69b, Main.Box@3c6e8659, Main.Box@17e2e2dd]
Main.Box@2452c4d
5
Static
Static
Static
Static
Static
Test1
```

Comment: what if yo do a view-source of the client-side html? and please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068678/which-xml-namespace-to-use-with-jsf-2-2 and use the namespaces in a consistent way And Test2 ... Test6 is not shown in the output? Just Test1?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155460/cforeach-not-recognized-anymore-after-migration-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-2. Might be that the jstl is just ignored if the namespace is not correct for your version. A view source might confirm this in you just seeing the `<c:foreach...` on the client side.

Comment: Test results that aren't showing don't produce results to show.  I'll review your links when I can.

Comment: The second link is actually what I was originally using to try namespaces, I'll have to try again later.

Comment: Updated jstl references to the latest I could find, and tried running the tests from Content_index with no avail.

Comment: What about my other question? The 'view source' thing? And please try the loops with different variable names (just to exclude things) and what if you put them in different orders? and what if you **also** print the variable value (i)

Comment: There are a couple more tests I thought of this morning, but when I inspect the page, nothing shows for the failed tests.

Comment: Can you update the namespaces too in this question. The code becomes 'better' then in general (for future users)

Comment: It's definitely in my libraries / configurations. I was able to get the tests to work in a new project: http://htkb.dyndns.org:8080/ForEachTest/index.xhtml

Comment: Great it works. If you summarize the differences, you have the cause.

Comment: I just have to rip out all the differences one by one and I'll find it, hopefully.  Imma leave this open until I get it, unless I have to recreate the whole thing.

Comment: So I am able to reproduce the for each test on the application site, but when I use the application format it fails.  I guess the next step would be to load the for each test with database info to see if that's failing it or maybe it's something with the way the page is created.

Comment: Debugging is easier... setting breakpoints in the getters...

Comment: So the for eaches only seem to fail when using the database information.  Might be worth setting up a debugging port (if they're even getting called) after all (default debug port is blocked by another service).

Comment: So it turns out if I pull the database information in the constructor, then it works, so the actual problem has to do with some order of operations where the for eaches don't have the information where the information can be displayed above the for eaches.

Comment: You most likely have the same problem using static data. And try without an include!

Comment: Current tests are not using the include, but it will eventually be mandatory, thus the need for the  c:foreach.

Comment: The actual problem is when the data is available, it would seem that the foreach runs before the set, but I've had this problem before.

Comment: Correction: I've never had this problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out that it doesn't actually have to do with the configuration, but it has to do with build vs render time (which is what led me to doing c:forEach as opposed to ui:repeat, needing an ui:include as I did).

Because the TargetBean (where the collection is) is dependent on the LoginBean, the TargetBean must be constructed by using the LoginBean's user id to get the collection from the database.  This must also be the first thing that happens so that the c:forEach loops have information to iterate over, and thus must also occur during build time (like c:forEach), so I had to put the call in the first c:forEach as I don't have other build time tags to use for my example.

Here's my test file where I was able get results displayed:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">


    Test 1:<br/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "0" end = "#{TargetBean.PullStructure(0).boxList.size()-1}">
        Result 1!<br/>
    </c:forEach>

    #{TargetBean}<br/>            
    #{TargetBean.structure.boxList}<br/>
    #{TargetBean.structure.getBoxList()}<br/>
    #{TargetBean.structure.boxList.get(0)}<br/>
    #{TargetBean.structure.boxList.size()}<br/>    
    <br/><br/>

    Static:<br/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "0" end = "4">
        #{i}: #{TargetBean.structure.boxList.get(i)}<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    Test 2:<br/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "1" end = "#{TargetBean.structure.boxList.size()-1}">
        Result 2!<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    Test 3:<br/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" items = "#{TargetBean.structure.getBoxList()}">
        Result 3!<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    Test 4:<br/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "1" end = "#{TargetBean.structure.getBoxList().size()-1}">
        Result 4!<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    Test 5:<br/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "1" end = "${TargetBean.structure.boxList.size()-1}">
        Result 5!<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    Test 6:<br/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" items = "${TargetBean.structure.getBoxList()}">
        Result 6!<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "1" end = "${TargetBean.structure.getBoxList().size()-1}">
        Test6<br/>
    </c:forEach>
    Test 7:<br/>
    <c:forEach var = "i" begin = "0" end = "${TargetBean.structure.boxList.size()-1}">
        #{TargetBean.structure.boxList.get(i)}<br/>
    </c:forEach>
</html>
```